# R: Remove Interpunct

Tags: r, trim, removing-whitespace

How do I remove an interpunct (aka interpoint, middle dot, middot) from a string? I am looking for something like trimws, but trimws doesn't work on the interpunct.
Cheers

Comment: Can you give a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and the code that is not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

I **believe** this is what you're looking for.

```
string <- c("· interpunct", "interpunct · interpunct", "interpunct · ")
#[1] "· interpunct"            "interpunct · interpunct" "interpunct · " 

sub("(?:\\s?)+·(?:\\s?)+", "", string)
#[1] "interpunct"           "interpunctinterpunct" "interpunct"
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for what you have written, but unfortunately not for my string. In my string, the interpunct looks like a space (not the symbol you write), but isn't removed with trimws. When I copy and paste the string into word, it gives me the interpunct symbol. The string came from a confidential document, so unfortunately I can't upload it here. Any idea how to identify and remove it?

Comment: Change the content of your confidential string to make it non-confidential by keeping the same "structure". Otherwise, we have to play the guessing game.

Comment: You probably just want to copy "that strange interpunct" character of yours and replace it with my interpunct character in the regex.

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for the help. When I copy and paste the character in R, it comes out as a white space. That means that I can't paste here an example, and copy and paste into the regex doesn't work either. The only time I have been able to see a difference, is when I copy and paste into word. Then I see the intepunct character. I don't know how I can copy the symbol here so that it appears correctly.